# Error in ARM template deployment : Additional properties not allowed: userAssignedIdentities

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-identity

I have a ARM template with below syntax, trying to add user assigned identity to  AZ load test resource.

```
 "resources": [
            {
                "type": "Microsoft.LoadTestService/loadtests",
                "apiVersion": "2021-12-01-preview",
                "name": "[parameters('name')]",
                "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                "tags": "[parameters('tags')]",
                "identity": {
                    "type": "userAssigned",
                    "userAssignedIdentities": {
                            "/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<RGNAME>/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/<identityName>": {}
                        }               
                }
            }
        ]
```

And I get below error during the deployment. Any suggestions on this error? I will remove the hardcoded resourceid part once I get pass preflight deployment.

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment: 1:02:15 PM - Error: Code=ObjectAdditionalProperties; Message=Additional properties not allowed: userAssignedIdentities. Paths in payload: '$.identity.userAssignedIdentities'
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the latest [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.loadtestservice/loadtests), the only acceptable values for the identity are either `SystemAssigned`, or `None` for the current api.

It does appear that the property is available on the older API version, `2021-09-01-preview`, per [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-testing/how-to-use-a-managed-identity?tabs=arm#set-a-user-assigned-identity).

Comment: thank you !! was unable to find this information ...

Comment: Its weird that in portal we can assign user assigned identities. the documentation says UserAssignedIdentities are acceptable.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-testing/how-to-use-a-managed-identity?tabs=arm

Comment: It sure does! It *is* in preview though, so it could be something they are working on. I would change the API version to what they have in their example: `"2021-09-01-preview"`